# Imbalance datasets with many categories, one hot encoded problem, having high F1 score but very low accuracy on validation set

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

```
loss='categorical_crossentropy'
activation='softmax'
Metrics used:
keras_metrics.precision(), 
keras_metrics.recall(), 
keras_metrics.f1_score(), 
'accuracy'
```

What am I doing wrong, I am using LSTM for classification of a multilabel problem that I have converted to one-hot encoding. The values other than Accuracy are high but accuracy is shockingly very low

[Accuracy comparison between train and validation sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gffNu.png)

[Loss Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upcMg.png)

Comment: Can you add your loss graph and logs generated during training.

Comment: Yes, I will add that asap.

Comment: @AniketBote The Loss comparison has been added. Kindly provide input on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its clearly a case of overfiting. You can see that training loss keeps on decreasing and test loss keeps on increasing.
Here are some tips to avoid overfitting:

**1. Try simpler model**
If your model has a complex architecture with too many neurons and layers you must reduce it.

**2. Get more training data**
The more trainig data you have the better is generalization of the model.

**3. Use regularization**
In order to reduce overfitting. Tensorflow has inbuilt regularizer like l1, l2 etc.

Take a look at [Link](https://elitedatascience.com/overfitting-in-machine-learning)

Comment: Thank you, I will try all these three things.

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote if the solution worked.